# Access Google Email address from android app

Tags: android, api

I am working on an android app in which I want to access google account information (email address) to send to my server that will log the request coming from the device
How do I access this information without forcing the user to sign in
I found a way in which we need to access contacts of user which would definitely seem an odd message to user
Is there a way we can access device google account email address without asking for user contacts permission

Comment: Oh, wouldn't that be nice, if we'd be able to get a user's private data without him knowing...

Comment: I am looking for some other permission asking for all contacts doesn't seems right to me
Imagine if I just need google account email address and I ask you to share all contacts

Comment: I see. In that case, you will want to search for authentication. Something like this: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/android

Comment: This suggestion requires to login using google Id. We are not forcing user to sign in. Is there any other permission that we can use to just get the user account id?

Requires Contacts access seems very odd when I just need account id. It might not sound good to user. Most of our user are denying it and our functionality is dependent on it

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way. You can use the permission rationale to explain to the user, why your app needs that permission.